# How to use finder-generator in Play SBT project

Tags: playframework, sbt, ebean

Can anyone explain how to configure the *finder-generator* SBT plugin in a Play framework project in order to use type-safe queries with my entity beans? There is literally no documentation on the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/ebean-orm-tools/finder-generator), and the [Ebean documentation](http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/query/typesafe) hardly has any actionable info on using the *finder-generator*.

Comment: Did you manage to get it running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, we had the move away from the whole type-safe queries thing due to extremely poor documentation, and unreasonably complicated integration with Play. If you have gone down this road, it will do you much good to quit.